# Push images to minikube docker daemon using palantir gradle-docker plugin

Tags: docker, gradle, minikube

I’m trying to make the plugin push images to minikube docker daemon as it’s stated [here.](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env)

From terminal I can do it using:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

I tried to do it in Gradle before the docker task:

```
val prepareMinikubeDocker by tasks.registering(Exec::class) {
    doLast {
        exec {
            executable = "eval"
            args("\$(minikube docker-env)")
    }
}

docker {
    dependsOn(prepareMinikubeDocker.get())
    name = "${project.name}:${project.version}"
    files("build/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar")
    copySpec.into("build/libs")
}
```

And it gives me the error:

```
Cannot run program "eval" (in directory "/Users/username/IdeaProjects/pet/MyService"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `eval` isn't a "real command"; it's a special shell built-in and you have to run it in the same context as the command you're trying to run.  I probably wouldn't try to hard-code a specific Docker environment into your build system, though; can you run `eval $(minikube docker-env); ./gradlew build` from the host shell instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah it worked, thank you!